# How to do multiple select in@SqlStr when using BCP

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, bcp

I have code like this run with no error and I got result.

```
DECLARE @fileName VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @sqlStr VARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @sqlCmd VARCHAR(1000)
SET @fileName = 'C:\SQL_Queries\test.xml'
SET @sqlStr = 'select * from ##tmpEmployeeJob FOR XML PATH(''EmployeeJob''), ROOT(''Pos.EmployeeJob'')'
SET @sqlCmd = 'bcp "' + @sqlStr + '" queryout ' + @fileName + ' -w -T'
EXEC xp_cmdshell @sqlCmd
```

But when I want to do multiple select in sqlstr like this

```
SET @sqlStr = 'select(select * from ##tmpEmployeeJob FOR XML PATH(''EmployeeJob''), ROOT(''Pos.EmployeeJob''),
select * from ##tmpCity FOR XML PATH(''City''), ROOT(''Pos.City''))'
```

I got this error

> Incorrect syntax near 'EmployeeJob'

How can I do the multiple select like above?

Comment: what's the error. i suspect you'll have multiple ones.

Comment: The error said Incorrect syntax near 'EmployeeJob'

Comment: I guess maybe @salstr in bcp does not support nested select like this. But anyone know what is the best approach?  Thank you so much

Comment: replace the `,` with `;` Also, it's hard to tell here but make sure @sqlStr is all on ONE LINE otherwise xp_cmdshell will interpret it like you hit a carriage return, thus breaking up your command on the command line interface.

Comment: @scsimon Sir, Thank you so much. It's worked

Comment: No problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

When you exporting xml you can easily compose xml strings from two or more queries. Or you can export table with more rows (where rows can be xml data type).